# DASH plotly bootstrap hide div on print

Tags: plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm using DASH app on Heroku that requires user to print out the page in PDF. I'm looking to 'save to pdf' option in the browser, however, a simple page print contains Div elements that are undesirable such as buttons. I'm using DASH BootStrap Components but I don't see any .d-print-none (Display in Print) options in their documentation. Is there a way I can hide div elements on printing? Apologies for the basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give each item you want to hide a certain `className`, and then set up a stylesheet with something like this:

```
@media print {
  .print-class { 
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `class_name` property of your `div` to `d-print-none`:

```
html.Div("YOUR CONTENT HERE", class_name = "d-print-none")
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/